# Plotting a GPS track

Tags: c++, qt, data-visualization

I have performed this test and they have not given me a conclusive answer (they really have not given me any response). I have to paint a graphic, do you think the implementation is correct? Is there any possible improvement?

---

Given a GPS track with variable number of points of latitude, longitude and
altitude (m).
Example: 39.98069380,0.02221786,512.0

**Assuming**

- You have Paint functions (you can assume that it paint point, line, a matrix
  of pixels or other kind of functions)
- You have list of points in memory in a matrix named Trackpoints[latitude,
  longitude,altitude]
- The screen resolution is 128x128
- Track can have 2 to 5000 points (consider performance issues)
- Distance between points should be determined by coordinates

**Task**

- Create a working module to paint graph of distance-altitude (meters)
- Graph should expand to whole X axis.
- Grey Horizontal bands are optional
- Vertical scale values are optional
- Fill graph area is optional
- Graph example attached
  [image]

---

Now my code:

I used qCustomPlot library and tryed to do the  code as simple as possible just with 4 classes

**Map.h**

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <random>

struct coordinate{
    double longitude, altitude, latitude;
};

class Map
{
public:
    Map(int total_points, double top_point);
    int total_coordinates;
    double highest_point;
    std::vector<coordinate> matrix_points;

private:
    double RandomNumber();
    std::vector<coordinate> GenerateCoordinates();
};
#endif // MAP_H
```

---

**Map.cpp**

```
#include "map.h"

using namespace std;

Map::Map(int total_points, double top_point)
{
    total_coordinates = total_points;
    highest_point = top_point;

   matrix_points = GenerateCoordinates();
}

double Map::RandomNumber()
{
    double random_value;

    // Generate a random between a margin
    static random_device rd;
    default_random_engine generator(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0, highest_point);

    random_value = distribution(generator);

    return random_value;
}

vector<coordinate> Map::GenerateCoordinates()
{
    coordinate coordi;
    vector<coordinate> track_points;

    for(int i = 0; i < total_coordinates; i++)
    {
        coordi.longitude = i;
        coordi.altitude = RandomNumber();
        coordi.latitude = RandomNumber();

        track_points.push_back(coordi);
    }

    return track_points;
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "map.h"

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Map map(50, 50.6);

    coordinate coordi;
    coordi.longitude = 39.98069380;
    coordi.altitude = 0.02221786;
    coordi.latitude = 512.0;

    Paint();
    Paint(map);
    Paint(coordi);

    ui->customPlot->replot();
}

// Paint map
void MainWindow::Paint()
{
    // Create graph and assign data to it:
    ui->customPlot->addGraph();

    // First graph will be filled with translucent blue
    ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 255, 20)));

    // Let the ranges scale themselves so graph 0 fits perfectly in the visible area:
    ui->customPlot->graph(0)->rescaleAxes();

    // Set blank axis lines
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTicks(false);
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabels(false);
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setTicks(false);
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setTickLabels(false);

    // make top right axes clones of bottom left axes:
    ui->customPlot->axisRect()->setupFullAxesBox();
}

void MainWindow::Paint(const Map map)
{
    QVector<double> x(map.total_coordinates), y(map.total_coordinates);

    for(int i = 0; i < map.total_coordinates; i++)
    {
        x[i] = map.matrix_points[i].longitude;
        y[i] = map.matrix_points[i].altitude;
    }

    // Create graph and assign data to it:
    ui->customPlot->addGraph();
    ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);

    // Set axes ranges, so we see all data:
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setRange(0, x.last());
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0, map.highest_point);
}

void MainWindow::Paint(const coordinate coordi)
{
    QCPAxis* yAxis = ui->customPlot->axisRect(0)->axis(QCPAxis::atLeft);

    // Red line
    QCPItemLine *item = new QCPItemLine(ui->customPlot);
    item->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
    item->start->setCoords(coordi.longitude, 0); // assuming 0 is always the lowest number
    item->end->setCoords(coordi.longitude, yAxis->pixelToCoord(ui->customPlot->size().height()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "map.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    void Paint();
    void Paint(const Map map);
    void Paint(const coordinate coordi);

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: You used the [tag:comparative-review] tag but I don't see multiple solutions there. Could you clarify this in your quesiton or remove the tag so that it is not confusing people? And could you explain what you mean by _Test_ in the title? There are no unit-tests. What kind of test is it?

Comment: @t3chb0t I think this is an interview-question rather than a programming-challenge and OP simply used the wrong words/tags to describe it.

Comment: Doesn't using existing plotting library defeat the purpose of a challenge?

Comment: Depends on the challenge.  “I know a library function to do that” is the *right* answer in most real-world “challenges” that I don’t see often enough.

Comment: @t3chb0t True it isn't a comparative, sorry for the msitake, it's my first time asking un SE. Yes it is not a test at all, it's like a programming challenge, sorry once.

Comment: @yuri If that is true it does not seem like an answer, it would seem like an excuse.

Comment: @ JDługosz I think I understand what you mean, the intention is to see that I can do it, even so, if I know a library that I can do it, why not use it? I'm right?

Answer (score 4):

## [Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You can, however, in a CPP file (not H file) or inside a function put individual `using std::string;` etc.  (See [SF.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).)

---

```
coordinate coordi;
coordi.longitude = 39.98069380;
coordi.altitude = 0.02221786;
coordi.latitude = 512.0;
```

Use an initializer, not a list of assignments after default initialization.  In this case, it is simply an aggregate, so you can write

```
coordinate coordi {39.98069380, 0.02221786, 512.0};
```

without having to change anything about the class.

---

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

---

I see a couple places where you are using *ye olde syntax* for intializations.

---

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

[⧺C.149](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c149-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-avoid-forgetting-to-delete-objects-created-using-new) — no naked `new` or `delete`.

You should probably make this a `unique_ptr` as a drop-in replacement without otherwise changing the architecture.  Then, you can get rid of the manually written destructor completely.

Or, in this case I see the object has the same lifetime as the container and you don’t do any pointer manipulation or whatever.  So why do you need a pointer at all, instead of just containing the object by value?

Comment: Totally agree with using namespace std argument, also with the object initialization, not using a list.

About the "delete ui" it's autogenerated code.